# Resetting a game to start over in java

Tags: java

I created a dice game between the user and computer that loops 10 rounds - but if one of the game rounds is a tie - then it will ask if you want to play again and restart the game. I'm having a problem with the last part as the game iterates over at random times now. Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("User vs. Computer Dice Game");

    boolean Correct = false;
    boolean Replay = false;

    while(Replay == true) {

    }
    while(Correct == false) {

        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? ");
        String a = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print(a);
        if (a.equals("yes")) {
            for(int i =1; i<11; i++) {

                Random rand = new Random();
                int usernum = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
                System.out.println("User rolled: "+usernum);
                Random rand2 = new Random();
                int computernum = rand2.nextInt(6)+1;
                System.out.println("Computer rolled: "+computernum);

                if (usernum > computernum) {
                    System.out.println("User wins");
                    System.out.println();
                }if (computernum > usernum) {
                    System.out.println("Computer wins");
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if(usernum == computernum) {
                    System.out.println("It\'s a tie!");
                    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) ");
                    System.out.println();
                    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                        Replay = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        Correct = false;
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When game is a tie , do you want to start new 10 roll on dice ? or only tied roll will reroll ?

Comment: Or instead of looping with variable `Correct`, why not loop over a counter? If the game is drawn, set the counter back to the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- You never set Correct=true.
- Once inside the "while (Correct==false)" loop, you never test Replay.
- There is no point in creating rand2.  Just reuse rand1.

You have "for (int i=1;i<11;i++)" for the main loop.
Inside of that loop, and it's a tie, you ask if you want to play again, but there is nothing there to end the loop, so the inner for loop will continue to play out until you hit 11.

You might add a break statement when it's a tie to abort the for loop.

In fact, you're probably better off just aborting the loop and then asking the question again at the top of the while loop:

```
while(Correct == false) {
    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? ");
    String a = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print(a);
    if (a.equals("yes")) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int usernum = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("User rolled: " + usernum);
            Random rand2 = new Random();
            int computernum = rand2.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("Computer rolled: " + computernum);

            if (usernum > computernum) {
                System.out.println("User wins");
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (computernum > usernum) {
                System.out.println("Computer wins");
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (usernum == computernum) {
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");

                // Exit early from the for loop:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Correct = true;
    }
}
```